# Simplifying a generic extension method

Tags: c#, generics

I have written a generic extension method, which basically adds a binding to a windows form ui element (like a form or a button).

It does work fine for now, tried it in a few projects, however it's still a quite complex method with 3 generic "T-arguments".

```
public static void Add<T1, T2, T3>(
    this ControlBindingsCollection collection,
    T2 dataSrc,
    Expression<Func<T1, T3>> p1,
    Expression<Func<T2, T3>> p2)
    where T1 : class 
    where T2 : class 
{
    var prop1Name = PropertyNameResolver.GetPropertyName(p1);
    var prop2Name = PropertyNameResolver.GetPropertyName(p2);
    collection.Add(prop1Name, dataSrc, prop2Name, false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}
```

GetPropertyName looks like this:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T1,T2>(Expression<Func<T1,T2>> propertyExpression)
{
    return ((MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body).Member.Name;
}
```

This are two examples of how I call the method:

```
DataBindings.Add<Form, FrmOptionsPresenter, double>(
    m_frmOptionsPresenter,
    binder => binder.Opacity,
    dataSrc => dataSrc.Opacity);
```

Like I've said above, the call kinda looks heavy.

What I would like to know now:
Is there anything you can suggest me to make these method more simple and readable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at our implementation:

```
public static class BindableComponentExtensions
{
    public static void Bind<T>(this IBindableComponent component, T value, Expression<Func<object>> controlProperty, Expression<Func<T, object>> modelProperty)
        where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        component.DataBindings.Add(new Binding(
            StringExtensions.PropertyName(controlProperty),
            value,
            StringExtensions.PropertyName(modelProperty),
            true,
            DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
    }

    public static void Bind<TComponent, T>(this TComponent component, T value,
        Expression<Func<TComponent, object>> controlProperty, Expression<Func<T, object>> modelProperty)
        where TComponent : IBindableComponent
        where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        component.DataBindings.Add(new Binding(
            StringExtensions.PropertyName(controlProperty),
            value,
            StringExtensions.PropertyName(modelProperty),
            true,
            DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
    }

    public static void OneWayBind<TComponent, T>(
        this TComponent component, T value, 
        Expression<Func<TComponent, object>> controlProperty, 
        Expression<Func<T, object>> modelProperty
    )
        where TComponent : IBindableComponent
        where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        component.DataBindings.Add(new Binding(
            StringExtensions.PropertyName(controlProperty),
            value,
            StringExtensions.PropertyName(modelProperty),
            true,
            DataSourceUpdateMode.Never));
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
combobox.Bind(name, c => c.SelectedValueId, v => v.OrganizationLegalFormId);
_auditName.OneWayBind(_model, c => c.Text, v => v.DisplayName);
```

Where `name` or `_model` is data model class, `c => c.SelectedValueId` or `c => c.Text` is control property, `v => v.DisplayName` or `v => v.OrganizationLegalFormId` is model property.

`StringExtensions.PropertyName` is your `PropertyNameResolver.GetPropertyName`:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string MethodName<T>(Expression<Action<T>> action)
    {
        return ReflectionExtensions.GetMethodInfo(action).Name;
    }

    public static string PropertyName<T, TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertyExpression)
    {
        return PropertyNameInternal(propertyExpression);
    }

    public static string PropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        return PropertyNameInternal(propertyExpression);
    }

    private static string PropertyNameInternal(LambdaExpression propertyExpression)
    {
        if (propertyExpression == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(@"propertyExpression");

        var memberExpression = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            var ubody = (UnaryExpression)propertyExpression.Body;
            memberExpression = ubody.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }

        if (memberExpression == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(@"The expression is not a member access expression.", @"propertyExpression");

        var property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (property == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(@"The member access expression does not access a property.", @"propertyExpression");


        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does look promising, let  me try it out :)

Comment: Could you give me your property name method aswell?